# Minimum MovementThreshold for GeoLocator

Tags: windows-phone-8, geolocation

I've started to use GeoLocator in my Windows Phone apps, instead of the old GeoCoordinateWatcher, so far, so good. The only problem I've found is that I can't find anywhere the minimum MovementThreshold for the GeoLocator, I know that for the GeoCoordinateWatcher, the minimum value is 2.5 meters. Anyone has any idea of the min value for GeoLocator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN, [the default is 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.movementthreshold), so I would assume that is the minimum.

Comment: that were my thoughts, however if try to define it to zero, I get an error in compile time with the message "Operation aborted", nothing else. So I started increasing that value until I reached 10 and then got no error, but the PositionChanged event was never called, at 100 mts for MovementTreshold It started to work

Comment: Hmm. I think it probably has something to do with the accuracy of the GPS in the device. I don't think they are actually accurate enough to use a `MovementThreshold` of 0, so maybe you just need to find the sweet spot. There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of info out there about the accuracy though, and I'm sure it varies from device to device.

Comment: I guess that is then, well.. then I think 100mts to 150mts are a decent minimum movement.